# delete using inner join

Tags: sql, join, using

I have the below 4 tables. I tried to do some PoC (proof of concept) on delete with join query. So I tried to delete the rows in table 't1' and 'mytable' based on the join query on 'table1' and 'table2'. The delete query with 't1' and 'mytable' are both showing unusual behaviours.
Below is the query and table definition for the four tables:

```
--query starts here


DELETE mytable
FROM Table2 t1
inner join
Table2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.col1        -- the query deletes all the rows from mytable

DELETE t1
FROM Table1
inner join
Table2 on table1.Col1=table2.col1   -- the query deletes all the rows from t1
```

Comment: What do you mean by `unusual behavior`, what is your desired result?

Comment: I am just experimenting with how delete works with join, that's why i am deleting from mytable based on the join condition in table t1 and t2. But that is deleting all the rows in mytable.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be the case if your first table have a relation to the second table. Perhaps you should edit your question and show what kind of data is in your database.

Comment: @PankajPandey - I have the query posted below. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving a join predicate for the target table so your queries are interpreted as CROSS JOINs.

This:

```
DELETE mytable
FROM Table2 t1
inner join
Table2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.col1
```

Is equivalent to this (will have same execution plan):

```
DELETE mytable
FROM mytable
cross join (Table2 t1
    inner join
    Table2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.col1)
```

And that's logically equivalent to this:

```
DELETE mytable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t1
    inner join
    Table2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.col1)
```

Which, if that subquery has at least one row is logically equivalent to this:

```
DELETE mytable
```

You're suppose to reference the object you're deleting from in the join.

Like:

```
DELETE mytable
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN Table2 t1
    ON ????
inner join Table2 t2 
    on t1.Col1=t2.col1
```

Or, if you're using an alias:

```
DELETE m
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN Table2 t1
    ON ????
inner join Table2 t2 
    on t1.Col1=t2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are looking for.  This query deletes the common data from table1 and table2 in mytable and t1.

```
   DELETE mytable
    WHERE COL1 IN (SELECT T1.COL1 FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.COL1=T1.COL1)

 DELETE T1 
    WHERE COL1 IN (SELECT T1.COL1 FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.COL1=T1.COL1)
```